# Programmaticaly click on a link in webbrowser using DOM delphi 7

Tags: delphi, dom, delphi-7

`<span id="lblCommande">Bon de commande</span></a>|

 <a href="retour.aspx">`

This is the link I want to "click" using a button. 
I know how to click a button using this:
`WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('ID HERE').Click;`
But that doesn'T work for links. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it. Here's how:
`WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('lblcommande').Click;`